# How to prevent Spotlight from playing YouTube videos when I paste a YouTube URL into Spotlight

Tags: macos, safari, catalina, spotlight

When I copy and paste a YouTube video URL into Spotlight (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>), it automatically starts playing that YouTube video in a miniaturised web browser embedded in Spotlight.

How do I turn off this behaviour? In fact I would most prefer to completely get rid of that embedded web browser entirely.

---

The reason I often paste stuff into Spotlight is that I use it like a second clipboard/storage space for text.

It's really convenient, a single keybind away. I often paste text there if I have to copy/paste something else intermittently, or need to be reminded of something a few moments later.

Comment: Why paste a URL into Spotlight at all if you don't want it to handle it, why not paste it directly into whatever you *do* want to handle it??

Comment: @Tetsujin I use Spotlight like a second clipboard. I have edited to include that, original question may have been A/B.

Comment: “I use Spotlight like a second clipboard.”  This is like using a crowbar as a second screwdriver - it’s the wrong tool completely.  If you need a scratchpad to hold some values, [Stickies](https://support.apple.com/guide/stickies/welcome/mac) is a perfect  solution for this.  If you really need extended clipboard functionality, there’s 3rd party apps like [Flycut](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12)

Comment: @Allan I can't switch to stickies with a single keybind, and I don't really want to install new imperfect software since Spotlight is already super convenient for me. Flycut is imperfect bc it seems to be only for code? Adds a new menu bar icon, and I don't check it frequently (I open Spotlight all the time, so I'm always reminded of anything I might have put into it)

Comment: Nothing you said about Stickies and Flycut is accurate.  Stickies is built in and like any app (built in or otherwise) you can assign a shortcut to it.  Flycut is not "only for code" and I don't see what having a menu bar icon has to do with how it actually functions.  Additionally, Flycut was just a single example - there are tons more.  Finally, Spotlight is a search tool - you don't put anything into it.  I think one of the (major) issues you're having is that you're trying to use tools outside of their design capabilities while ignoring the appropriate ones.

Comment: This sentence.... "I don't really want to install new imperfect software"  Do you know of any "perfect" software?

Comment: @Allan rarely. What I meant by that is, Spotlight already exists and is extremely convenient and close to perfect for me. So for me it would only be worth installing an additional app for this if it truly fit my every need and was as if not more convenient to use.

Comment: I'm not sure where I'm not being clear that 1) stickies is built in and included with macOS and 2) you're using spotlight incorrectly - this is why you're not getting your desired results.  Thusly, the question can't be answered because Spotlight isn't failing nor is it capable of doing what you want.

Comment: I understand you use Spotlight that way. I do it time and time again, for example, to strip formatting from copied text. Why don't you **first** type some character and **then** paste the URL? For example, typing `a` and then the URL will produce `ahttp://`. Spotlight won't interpret the string as a URL and won't play the video, problem (kind of) solved. After editing the URL, you just need to pay attention not to copy that first character.

Comment: @jaume good workaround thank you for pointing it out! I would still prefer to find out how to turn off that web browser. When I open spotlight again all the text is highlighted, I like cmd-x cmd-space cmd-v so quick, with that workaround I would be forced to delete that character from the start.

Comment: As I see it, the "culprit" is not Spotlight, but Quick Look. Spotlight just displays a Quick Look preview of the top hit (or of any selected item, for that matter). You would need to prevent Quick Look from being able to display a preview of a web page, then Spotlight wouldn't (be able to) play the video.

Comment: After some research on macOS 10.15.4 "Catalina", the Quick Look bundles/plugins that seem responsible for creating web page previews are `/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/Web.qldisplay` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuickLookUI.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/QLWebBundle.bundle`. I guess they are related, but I don't know how they get launched, since they aren't listed in the output of `qlmanage -m`, and don't know how to deregister them, either.

Comment: @jaume please could you turn "first type some character and then paste the URL" into an answer?

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me, I've added an answer and explanded it to mention Big Sur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With macOS 10.15 Catalina, as a **workaround**, you can first type a character and then paste the URL to fool Spotlight and prevent it from displaying a Quick Look preview. After editing the URL, you just need to pay attention not to copy that first character.

With macOS 11 Big Sur, **none of that is necessary**, as Spotlight no longer displays a preview:
[image]